# Is there a way to give a specific file name when saving a file via cURL?

Tags: macos, curl, terminal

I am pulling files using curl in the mac OS X terminal and want to give them different names. Is there a way to specify a name, such as a "save as" function when using curl?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Either use the [`-o` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o) or its alias `--output`, or redirect shell output to the file of choice by using `>`.

```
curl -o /path/to/local/file http://url.com
curl http://url.com > /path/to/local/file
```

If you want to preserve the original file name from the remote server, use the [`-O` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-O) or its alias `--remote-name`.

```
curl -O http://url.com/file.html
```

Stores the output from the remote location in the current directory as file.html.

Comment: Especially helpful given the Chrome "Copy to curl url" feature because an output file name can be appended easily.

Comment: I used this method, but I kept downloading a corrupted file. The issue was that the download URL had a redirect, but adding the `-L` flag (follow redirects) solved my issue.

Answer (score 24):

`curl -o <name> <url>` seems to do the trick..

*HINT*: You can also try with `man curl`...

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to download a file to another file name, and allow redirects. No need to look for `-L` in the comments.

`curl -L "$URL" -o "$FILENAME"`

Example

`curl -L https://protonmail.com/download/bridge/protonmail-bridge_2.1.1-1_amd64.deb -o bridge.deb`

Comment: what does `-L` do ?

Comment: @divine follows redirects

Answer (score 1):

For those who are getting familiar with CURL, here is a more clear and easy to understand use case example:

REMOTE URL

```
http(s)://my-remote-image.png?token=TOKEN_ID
```

CURL COMMAND IN ACTION (lowercase "o")

```
curl -o custom_name_to_be_used.png "http(s)://my-remote-image.png?token=TOKEN_ID"
```