# Download files with curl with timestamp or different name?

Tags: php, curl, download

Is there's a command to download files with curl from the same page and rename it with numbers or timestamps instead or rewritten the file with the `.php` file? I mean the url is `downloadfile.php?id=1500` so when I set the option `-O` I get a file called `downloadfile.php` and if I download the `id=1501` the `downloadfile.php` is rewritten it is possible to set curl to rename every curl request to number or timestamp like `downloadfile00001.php`?

Comment: [This might be a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744973/is-there-a-way-to-give-a-specific-file-name-when-saving-a-file-via-curl-in-mac-o)

Comment: curl -o <name> <url>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using flags it sounds like you are working on the commandline. -O uses the same name as the remote file. -o means write to file with whatever name you want. So in your script be it bash or what have you, you would use a variable you increment with the version you want.

example: curl website.com -o websitenamefileiwant.html

Answer (score 0):

in bash scripting you'd do this

```
filenames=( filename1.html filename2.html filename3.html )

    curl -s -o "${filenames[i]}" <url>
```

or you can do this on the command line

```
sudo curl http://path-to-url/downloadfile.php?id=1500 -o downloadfile00001.php
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the bash script but when I run I get filename1.html and that is rewritten again. 


`filenames=( filename1.html filename2.html filename3.html )

    curl -s -o "${filenames[i]}" <url>
    curl -s -o "${filenames[i]}" <url>
    curl -s -o "${filenames[i]}" <url>
    curl -s -o "${filenames[i]}" <url>`