# Change File Download Name with Curl To Download Link?

Tags: curl, wget

I've got a list of my sites in a file such as
site1.com/1.txt
site2.com/1.txt
site3.com/1.txt etc..

I'm using curl to download the file on my sites which often update, I would like for the file to be renamed rather than 1.txt to the url where it was downloaded, it it possible with curl? How would I do so? I'm open to using either curl or wget.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744973/is-there-a-way-to-give-a-specific-file-name-when-saving-a-file-via-curl

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91570/write-output-of-wget-or-curl-to-a-custom-filename-based-on-the-url <-- more flexible with details